# Write ID f selected feature to txt/csv

Tags: qgis, select

I want a code or an option in QGIS or in a web map using Qgis2web (in leaflet or openlayers), when I click on a feature on the map, automatically it should register the ID (from attribute table) of the feature in an text document  file or in a csv file.

Is it possible?